# How to extract different patterns in string in R?

Tags: r, regex, string, nlp

I want to extract a pattern of phrases from the following sentences.

```
text1 <- "On a year-on-year basis, the number of subscribers of Netflix increased 1.15% in November last year."

text2 <- "There is no confirmed audited number of subscribers in the Netflix's earnings report."

text3 <- "Netflix's unaudited number of subscribers has grown more than 1.50% at the last quarter."
```

The pattern is `number of subscribers` or `audited number of subscribers` or `unaudited number of subscribers`.

I am using the following pattern `\\bnumber\\s+of\\s+subscribers?\\b` from a previous problem (Thanks to @wiktor-stribiżew) and then extracting the phrases.

```
find_words <- function(text){
  
  pattern <- "\\bnumber\\s+of\\s+subscribers?\\b" # something like this

  str_extract(text, pattern)

}
```

However, this extracts the exact `number of subscriber` not the other patterns.

Desired output:

find_words(text1)

> 'number of subscribers'

find_words(text2)

> 'audited number of subscribers'

find_words(text3)

> 'unaudited number of subscribers'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See if this works

```
find_words <- function(text){

pattern <- "(audited |unaudited )?number\\s+of\\s+subscribers"

str_extract(text, pattern)

}
```

You can test it with the sample texts you provided:

```
find_words(text1)
# 'number of subscribers'
find_words(text2)
# 'audited number of subscribers'
find_words(text3)
# 'unaudited number of subscribers'
```

Comment: Alternative version: `"(un)?(audited )?number\\s+of\\s+subscribers?\\b"`